# OData from Linq

Tags: c#, odata

I have tables

- `Company` with fields `CompanyId`, `CompanyName`
- `Branch` with fields `BranchId`, `BranchName`, `CompanyId`
- `Employee` with fields `EmployeeId`, `EmployeeName`, `BranchId`.

I created OData service which returnes companies - pretty straightforward, directly from table. How can I create OData service , which returns employees data with `CompanyId` in them? I am using Entity Framerowk Core. Basically, I imagine as source instead of table it should have some join or Linq expression.

Comment: Will this work for you?
~Employees?$expand=$Branch(select=CompanyID)
The the response will like 
{
    EmployeeID:"ID",
    Branch:
    {
         CompanyID:"ID2"
    }
}